# Cannot add event listener to array elements

Tags: javascript

I want to add `mouseover` event to every link with `linkLink` class with JS.
Console gives an error - `Cannot read property style of undefined`. 
Whenever I set index manualy like - `l[0].addEventListener(...)` it 
works fine, but not with variable `i`. Any help?

```
var l = document.getElementsByClassName('linkLink');

for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    l[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() { l[i].style.backgroundColor = "black"; });
        if ((i % 2) === 0) l[i].style.color = "crimson";
        else l[i].style.color = "gold";
}
```

```
<a class="linkLink" href="#">link I</a><br>
<a class="linkLink" href="#">link II</a><br>
<a class="linkLink" href="#">link III</a><br>
```

Comment: a.linkLink:hover{ styles here }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `li[i]` in the handler function.

```js
var l = document.getElementsByClassName('linkLink');

for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    l[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() { this.style.backgroundColor = "black"; });
    //return back to original background color on mouseleave.
    l[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() { this.style.backgroundColor = "white"; });
    if ((i % 2) === 0) l[i].style.color = "crimson";
    else l[i].style.color = "gold";
};
```

```html
<a class="linkLink" href="#">link I</a><br>
<a class="linkLink" href="#">link II</a><br>
<a class="linkLink" href="#">link III</a><br>
```